# Constructor Calls Overridable Method Sonar

Tags: java, constructor, sonarqube, overriding

I am working on code clean up . During this process, i have come across lot of classes(UI screen popups and panels) in my project which are initializing other UI components in the constructors.

For instance,

```
public ScreenPopUpExample(var1, var2)
{
super();
this.var1 = var1;
this.var2 = var2;

initializeComponents();
}
```

Now in initializeComponents has methods which are in turn calling other methods.

For instance,

```
private final void initializeComponents()
{
 setUpToolbar();
 setUpDataSources();
 addEventHandlers(); 
}

private final void setUpToolbar() { // some code}
private final void setUpDataSources() { // some code}
private final void addEventHandlers() {// some code}
```

Though none of these classes are inherited in any way,for sonar to clear out these issues,
I made all the methods calling from ScreenPopUpExample's constructor as final and then executed the sonar report.
However the sonar still reports "**Constructor Calls Overridable Method**" in all these classes.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions/advices.

Comment: Are you sure those private methods don't themselves call overridable methods? Also, private methods are implicitely final. The final keyword is redundant.

Comment: It turns out that there are some methods buried deep inside, which are indeed overridden. Thanks JB Nizet.